# Unable to deploy Firebase Function | Error: Invalid Bucket Name

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

EDIT: This was caused by an issue with Firebase. The only solution was to wait until they fixed the platform. I was able to deploy without any issues the next day. Thank you.

I'm trying to deploy a function to firebase functions (gen 2) and I'm running into an error.

> Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error

When I run the deployment with the `--debug` flag it outputs the log showing that it failed to generate manifest from function:

> [2023-09-28T19:08:20.709Z] Got response code 400; body Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Invalid bucket name buckets/custom-bucket-name.appspot.com
> shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit

In my code I'm using the default bucket:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const Storage = admin.storage().bucket();
```

The frustrating part is that I deployed this yesterday without any issues.

Any ideas/suggestions of where to go from here?

I've tried redeploying the function from scratch (delete and redeploy) with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

It looks indeed like something broke since yesterday, and we're seeing multiple reports in our support team too. The engineering team rolled back the change that most likely caused this problem.